# get the hovered date from an ajax fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

[image: snip]i am using a jquery Full Calendar that displays info of my data on each date, based on the response from ajax.

```
    $('.mycalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
 $('.mycalendar').fullCalendar({
     eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
     },
    eventMouseover: function (data, event, view) {
      console.log("mouse is hovered on a date");
     //get the date on which mouse is hovered
   }
 });
```

how to get the date from the calendar on mouse hover using 'eventMouseover' event handler?
so that i can process the data based on this date, since data i wanted to show varies based on the date use has hovered on calendar.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to the callback is the calendar event object. This contains the start and end dates of the event. So you can write something like

```
eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
  console.log("mouse hovered over an event which starts on " + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD")  + " and ends on " +event.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
}
```

Of course if the event spans multiple days it cannot tell you precisely which day is being hovered.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventMouseover and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object for more details.

Comment: i get data from ajax which contain start and end date , i am suppose to show different data based on the date mouse is hovered.

Comment: well, the short answer to that is, it's not possible, sorry. What I've shown you above is the closest thing you can do.

Comment: If you are willing to do it based on clicking (instead of hovering) then you can use [dayClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayClick) which will fire whenever the user clicks on a specific day. From that you can get the clicked date and use it in your code.

Comment: yeah, this way i was able to get the specific date, thankq